# Where can I buy logos/get someone to design a logo, that will only be used by me once paid for?

Tags: logo

The reason i ask this is that i plan once i have chosen/created/bought a logo i plan to use it on items to start selling.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can hire a graphic designer to design a logo for you. That's one of the things that graphic designers do.